# Android URL FileNotFoundException Error

Tags: android, url, inputstream

I am trying to get a file off the internet and im running into some errors. If I have http:// in front of the link it throws a UnkownHostException but if i remove the http:// it gives me a protocal not found error.

my url connection line of code is

```
String urlS = "http://www.google.com/robots.txt";

URL url = new URL(urlS);

InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

any help thanks

Comment: Are you sure the file is there?  I know it sounds like a dumb question, but typos happen...

Comment: The URL comes back not found in the web browser...

Comment: is it possible you missed the privileges in the manifest

Comment: @Sam Quest I have added the permissions android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, and android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in my manifest. Also even if i change my link to http://www.google.com/robots.txt I still get UnkownHostException in LogCat. Any help thanks

Comment: sometimes restarting your emulator, if you are using one, helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of off topic, but:

You probably want to stay away from url.openStream();  It could just hang since no timeout with it?
[url openstream might leaving you hanging](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/09/10/urlopenstream-might-leave-you-hanging/)

You probably want to use the Apache HttpClient.